# Elisp - Loop over an alist

Tags: emacs, elisp

What's the best way to loop over an alist and do something with each pair in Emacs Lisp?  I suppose a macro wouldn't be difficult, I'm just wondering if this is built in somewhere.  Is there a more elegant way than below?

```
(setq my-list '((a . 1)
                (b . 2)
                (c . 3)))

(loop for key in (mapcar 'car my-list)
      for value in (mapcar 'cdr my-list)
      collect (cons value key))

;; Returns this
((1 . a)
 (2 . b)
 (3 . c))
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[*cl-loop*](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Loop-Facility.html) from *cl-macs.el* has support for destructing like CL:

```
(cl-loop for (key . value) in my-list
      collect (cons value key))
```

Comment: Now that `cl` is deprecated, the modern equivalent of this is to use the identically-featured `cl-loop` macro from `cl-lib`. That library is built into newer emacs versions and a backwards-compatible package is available from GNU ELPA.

Comment: What does "collect" mean here?

Answer (score 19):

Another way to do this without `loop` is with `mapcar` and a lambda.  I don't think it's any more elegant, but it's more idiomatic for elisp as opposed to Common Lisp:

```
(mapcar (lambda (element)
      (let ((key (car element))
            (value (cdr element)))
      (cons value key)))
      '((1 . a) (2 . b)))
```

Comment: I like this answer better, Since it does not use `cl`.

Comment: @kindahero You realize loop is a cl macro right?  It's perfectly fine.

Comment: Note, however, that byte compilation warns about using mapcar for side effects, ie. at the top level, where its return value is ignored. For simple iteration, `dolist` is preferred.

Comment: @sanityinc This should be in an answer.

Answer (score 19):

It's not clear what exactly you want to do -- the question is very general. There are many ways to loop over an alist and act on some or all of its entries. You show one way yourself.  Look also at `while` and, in particular, `dolist`.  This is your example using `dolist`:

```
    (let ((res  ()))
     (dolist (x my-list)
       (push (cons (cdr x) (car x)) res))
     (nreverse res))
```

(There is probably a better way to use `loop` than in your example -- no need to build three lists (two `mapcar`s + `loop`), for instance.)

Answer (score 7):

[`dash.el`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) provides many list manipulation functions like [maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29). Those that accept functions as arguments are also have [anaphoric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphoric_macro) counterparts. This allows for terse [functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) code. `dash.el` functions start with a dash, hence the name, and anaphoric versions start with 2 dashes. So [ataylor's variant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8512038/596361) would look much better like this:

```
(--map (cons (cdr it) (car it)) '((1 . a) (2 . b))) ; ((a . 1) (b . 2))
```